# Sorting sequence based on greatest common division

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a question. I write this comparator:

```
bool cmp(int a, int b)
{
   return __gcd(a, b) > 1;
}
```

and, for example:

if I have these numbers:

```
2 5 6 7 8 12 15 19 20
```

my code outputs:

```
20 15 12 8 6 2 5 7 19
```

it's okay..

but for example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

my code outputs

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How can I do this?

this sequence should be something like this:

```
9 6 3 (...)
```

Comment: Presumably you are using `std::sort`? This can't work. `std::sort` requires [*strict weak ordering*](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), which basically means it has to sort like normal numbers. E.g. `3<4`, so `!(4<3)`. But `gcd` is *commutative* `gcd(a,b) == gcd(b,a)` - it works the same either way round, so for that reason (and others), your `cmp` can't make sense for sorting. As it is, I'm not sure what order you are trying to achieve anyway.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what order you are trying to achieve. I can't see that it makes sense for one element to be "bigger" than another if they have non-trivial gcd, when both will be "bigger" than each other. This isn't a programming bug, it's a maths bug. Think about what you really want. Does it actually make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator does not establish [strict weak ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), so results are undefined.

To make proper comparator you must make sure that following is true:

`cmp(a, a) == false` — your comparator does not pass the test on `cmp(2, 2)`

`cmp(a, b) == true → cmp(b, a) == false` — your comparator does not pass the test on `cmp(2, 4)`

`cmp(a, b) == true and cmp(b, c) == true → cmp(a, c) == true` — your comparator does not pass the test on `cmp(2, 6) and cmp(6, 3)`

Comment: @JanKo You need to think about your sorting criteria again. Why should sorted sequence start with `9, 6, 3`? Why not `8, 4, 2`? Why not `3, 6, 9`, `6, 3, 9` or other 3 combinations? In what order should numbers `2, 4` be placed after sort? Why? You will see, that having a common divisor is not enough to establish unambiguous order and you will be forced to give additional criteria.

Comment: truth is indifferent created a sequence , it's important to build on the gcd

Comment: @JanKo It sounds like [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe you do not need sort, but some clusterisation algorithm instead?

Comment: I don't why how I can do this withou sort..